# Python - Loop Through List and Remove from Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My goal is to simply loop through a string, look up each character in the keys of a dictionary, and remove that key. This is what I have now:

```
def m(z,word):
    for char in word:
        if char in z:
            z = z.pop(char)      
        else:
            return False
    print True
    return z

print m({'m':1,'y':2,'z':3},'my')
```

I understand the error "argument of type 'int' is not iterable," but I'm not clear on the most straightforward way of correcting this.

Comment: You probably want `z.pop(char, None)` rather than `z = z.pop(char)`.

Comment: just use `del z[char]` instead of `pop`

Comment: You should include the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 4):

`z.pop(char)` removes the key `char` and returns the corresponing value. Replace

```
z = z.pop(char)
```

with

```
z.pop(char)
```

or use `del z[char]`.

Comment: or `z.pop(char, None)` if you want to avoid key errors from words that appear multiple times...